# What versions of visual studio can be used for the latest embedded series of windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, embedded

This is about Windows embedded compact 7, and its predecessor CE 6

Windows embedded compact 7, is a product that does exist, its for industrial solutions : http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx

Two questions

- What kind of versions of visual studio can be used with it?
- And is there a trial version of visual studio for them, or is programming on embedded devices only possible with pro versions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, only VS2008 is supported.
They said somewhere in 2011 that they MAY support Win Embedded 7 in 2010, but never did it. In VS2012 there's only support for Win Embedded 2013.

Source for 2012: [see comment from David Champbell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2012/10/04/visual-studio-2012-to-support-windows-embedded-compact.aspx)

Source for 2010: [See bottom of the page under comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154201.aspx)

I ran into the same problem early last year...

As far as I know, you can still download at least a demo version of VS2008

Comment: So to program windows embbeded compact 7 i should use 2008 ?
Also you talk about embedded 2013; i've not heard of it before is it allready available ?.

Comment: I'm no longer working with Windows Embedded, but if MS's plans didn't change, it should be released in March 2013, except for the compact version. That is scheduled for "first half of 2013"... See also: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-roadmap.aspx